# How to process this captcha image for Pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to solve automatically captchas like this one (all of them with red background and white letters) with Pytesseract

[image: Captcha image]

I have been trying processing image to make Pytesseract be able to read it, but no success. Would be great to receive your ideas to process this image. Here my code:

```js
import cv2
import pytesseract

tessdata_dir_config = '--tessdata-dir "C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata"'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread("captcha.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
adaptive = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
    gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 85, 20)
print((pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=tessdata_dir_config)).strip())
print((pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, config=tessdata_dir_config)).strip())
print((pytesseract.image_to_string(adaptive, config=tessdata_dir_config)).strip())

cv2.imshow("Captcha", img) # Output: IMQW
cv2.imshow("Gray", gray) # Output: IMOW
cv2.imshow("Adaptive", adaptive) # Output: IMOW,

cv2.waitKey(7000)
```

Comment: `Pytesseract` works even well but with normal text. For non-standard text (like in captcha) you may have to learn own `Deep Network` but it is not so easy.

Comment: The whole point of CAPTCHA is that it's difficult for OCR to read.

Answer (score 11):

I have a three-step solution

---

- 1. Resize
- 2. Closing
- 3. Threshold

---

**Step-1: Resize**

---

Resizing the image enables the OCR-algorithm to detect the character or digit strokes in the input image.

**Step-2: Closing**

---

[Closing](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) is a morphological operation aims to remove the small-holes in the input image.

If we look carefully `Q` and `W` characters consists of lots of small holes.

**Step-3: Threhsold**

---

We will apply [simple-threhsolding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) to binarize the image. Our aim to remove any leftover artifacts from the image.

| **Resize** | **Closing** | **Threshold** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Result:

```
IMQW
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("QUfxY.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*2, h*2))
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, None)
thr = cv2.threshold(cls, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75168470/read-numbers-on-image-using-ocr-python?