# Read numbers on image using OCR python

Tags: python, opencv, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to extract numbers on images using OpenCV in Python and tesseract. Here's my try but I got nothing. The code doesn't return the expected numbers

```
import fitz, pytesseract, os, re
import cv2

sTemp = "Number.png"
directory = '.\MyFolder'

def useMagick(img):
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    command = 'magick convert {} -resize 1024x640 -density 300 -quality 100 {}'.format(img, sTemp)
    os.system(command)

def readNumber(img):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
    print(txt)
    try:
        return re.findall(r'\d+\s?\/\s?(\d+)', txt)[0]
    except:
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (3,3), 0)
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(blur)
        try:
            return re.findall(r'\d+\s?\/\s?(\d+)', txt)[0]
        except:
            return 'REVIEW'

sPath = os.path.join(directory, sTemp)
useMagick(sPath)
x = readNumber(sPath)
print(x)
```

Here's sample of the images
[image]

The code doesn't return any digits. How can I improve the quality of such an image to be able to extract the numbers?

Answer (score 3):

After many searches, I could finally solve the problem

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import os, re

sImagesPath = r'MyFolder/'
mylist = []

def replace_chars(text):
    list_of_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
    result_number = ''.join(list_of_numbers)
    return result_number

for root, dirs, file_names in os.walk(sImagesPath):
    for file_name in file_names:
        img = cv2.imread(sImagesPath + file_name)
        gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 181, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 10)
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, lang='eng',config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
        mylist.append(replace_chars(txt))
        print(replace_chars(txt))

with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in mylist:
        s = ''.join(map(str, i))
        f.write(s + '\n')
```